# How to get user defined input for defining threshold in python script

Tags: python, scanpy

Here basically I'm read a file of `h5ad`file format of a single cell data.

What I'm doing is to read the files and define a filter which I can do manually mean hardcoded which works.

My objective is build a function kind of where user just gives a `h5ad` file as input then define no of genes and no of cells to keep which can be used as filtering parameter for the single cell data.

So far my code is this

```
import loompy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scanpy as sc

sc.settings.verbosity = 3  # verbosity: errors (0), warnings (1), info (2), hints (3)
sc.settings.set_figure_params(dpi=80, color_map='Greys')
sc.logging.print_versions()
```

**#Reading the data**

```
adata = sc.read_h5ad('/Single_cell/cerebellar_development/508cf892-174c-45ab-b2dc-05f54f1ee7ed/aldinger20.processed.h5ad')
adata

obs: 'orig.ident', 'nCount_RNA', 'nFeature_RNA', 'sample_id', 'percent.mito', 'S.Score', 'G2M.Score', 'Phase', 'CC.Difference', 'nCount_SCT', 'nFeature_SCT', 'age', 'figure_clusters', 'sex', 'type', 'experiment', 'fig_cell_type', 'n_genes', 'n_genes_by_counts', 'total_counts', 'total_counts_mt', 'pct_counts_mt'
    var: 'name', 'n_cells', 'mt', 'n_cells_by_counts', 'mean_counts', 'pct_dropout_by_counts', 'total_counts'
    obsm: 'X_pca', 'X_umap', 'X_tsne'
```

**#Next Step is where I define the filter**

```
sc.pp.filter_cells(adata, min_genes=500)
sc.pp.filter_genes(adata, min_cells=10)
print(adata.n_obs, adata.n_vars)
```

**#Once the above steps happen**
The next step is to save the filtered data file as `h5ad` format.

So to make it simple I this whole process to be automated sort of where it can take user input as **file input** and then define the **filter** then run the code and save the filtered output

Comment: You can use e. g. the `configparser` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html?highlight=config#module-configparser which helps to process simple configuration files which can easily be written and edited by a human.

Comment: the goal is only the user would run the program and just define the threshold

Comment: It is not clear to me if the user should enter the threshold interactively when starting the program or if the program should read it from file which filled the user beforehand.

Comment: okay I will try to make it clear , the user should have option of of setting a defined number such as such as ` min_genes=500 min_cells=10` which I have defined , here instead of this predefined number the user should define any no

Comment: **How** should the user define the values?

Comment: im trying to make it in jupyter notebook so it can be like three field which user can see such as `file location` then  `Min genes`, `Min cells`